# Pass apple store review: app with selected users

Tags: ios, app-store

I have problem passing the apple store review because my app should be available only to users already selected outside the app. So other random people essentially should not access the app. This flow however is tecnically against the apple policies. Here is the question: there are apps like innercircle (https://www.theinnercircle.co) that were able to overcome the policies. Do you know how they did it?

Comment: What do you mean by "available"? There seems to be no restriction on Inner Circle apart from needing an account.

Comment: Your confusing the example you provided (theinnercircle) and the one you explained. That example is generic, it gives EVERYONE access to the app, but through user preferences and settings they only connect with people with similar interest or 'circles'. You can't restrict access to an app. But you can filter features or settings based on a users preference. You would have to provide more detail on apples feedback and the steps you've already taken. From your description, "random people should not access the app" is grounds for rejection. But if you've implemented user profiles that's different

Comment: I have tons of apps on the store that require a login to use. (I.e. Most premium SaaS apps) Really depends how you phrase and display stuff. Without screenshots, user flow etc it's hard to help you.